# Store location in CoreData (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I'm trying to figure out how to store locations in `CoreData` from `JSON`.
I am using this code to get data from the `JSON` api and trying to store it in my `CoreData`

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let newPok = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: context)

for jsonItem in json {   
    let item = jsonItem as! NSDictionary

    let pokemonName = item["name"]
    let pokemonDesc = item["description"]
    let pokemonLat = (item["location"] as! NSDictionary) ["latitude"]
    let pokemonLon = (item["location"] as! NSDictionary) ["longitude"]

    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pokemonLat as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: pokemonLon as! CLLocationDegrees)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.title = pokemonName as! String?
    annotation.subtitle = pokemonDesc as! String?

    annotation.coordinate = coordinates

    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    newPok.setValue(pokemonName as! String, forKey: "name")
    newPok.setValue(pokemonDesc as! String, forKey: "desc")
    newPok.setValue(pokemonLat as! String, forKey: "lat")
    newPok.setValue(pokemonLon as! String, forKey: "lon")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("not saved")
    }
}
```

But when I run this code I always get a `fatal exception`.

```
error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "(null)" UserInfo={entity=Person, property=lat, reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible}
```

My Database has a setup with 4 string(name,desc,lat,long)

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Kind regards,

Johan

Comment: Type of `lat` in core-data?

Comment: type is string. but I think that is not correct

Comment: That indentation though... o.0

Comment: Do you mean your CoreData entity contains four string property??
If so check the pokemanLat and pokemanLon, what is the type you are getting there?

Comment: Yes, string is the property of all attributes.

I think I'm getting a dictionary because I cast my variables to NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the data type of Lat and Long Attribute from `String` to `Integer16`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I need to cast my variables (pokemonlat, pokemonlon) to something else? or is string good enough

Comment: You have to cast both of them from string to integer or numeric

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.

I changed my Core data attribute from `string` to `double` and in my code I did `pokemonLat as! Double?`. That worked.

Thanks for your help guys! appricate it!

Comment: that will work only in case if you 100% sure that your JSON response from server contains lat/lon AS number, not wrapped in quotes as string. You will get a crash otherwise.
So maybe would be better to write something like this:

    let lat: Double? = dictionary["lat"].flatMap { Double($0) }